# Badge Propsal: Vacation

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

A while ago I discovered the [Fanatic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/83/fanatic) badge.  After a couple of shaky starts of hitting 20-30 consecutive days, I really hit the groove and it became routine.  The badge was mine.

By that time, Stack Exchange had become part of my routine - the hot network questions usually provides some interesting and/or entertaining reading over breakfast, and it's easy to dip into it with the mobile app.  I now easily reached 200+ consecutive days.

Last week I went camping.  The mobile signal at the campsite was non-existent - oh well, there goes my run.  However, there were times when we were out and about where there was enough signal, and I found myself "just having a quick look" now and again, when in fact, I really shouldn't have been - I was on holiday!  But, you know, habits and all.

I propose a new badge - Vacation - probably Gold, but possibly Silver.  It would be awarded to people who *don't* visit the site for 5+ consecutive days, but *only after visiting for 200+ consecutive days*.  This badge could be awarded multiple times.

This badge would be a reward for visiting the site over and above the Fanatic badge, but also recognise that everyone needs a break sometimes; if I'd known there would be a badge waiting for me, I probably wouldn't have popped open the app "just to see", and spent more time actually looking at the things actually around me.

Comment: I'd be interested in some comments by the downvoters - at the end of the day, the Fake Internet Points and Badges are all just a bit of fun, right?

Answer (score 10):

There are thousands here that *really* appreciate your sentiment, I blew mine by *one day* due to a cancelled flight and no 3G coverage where we were staying. Starting over again was painful, I think I cried a little, at least on the inside.

This amounts to more of a consolation prize than actual behavior that we'd want to *encourage*, even though I'd quickly point out that more than a few of you probably need to spend less time in front of your computers.

If you come within a week of earning it and narrowly miss it, [contact us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) with your tale of woe and we'll probably send you some stickers. If you have the presence of mind and planning skills to *know* you're going to miss it due to a vacation or something, contact us ahead of time and we might even send you a shirt in awe of your superior planning skills that you can sport on your trip.

For best results: indicate women's or men's US size, your full name and shipping address, and a funny joke if you have one.

Comment: I am a fanatic, so I can't get the stickers or the T-shirt now. :(

Comment: Note to self: Plan a vacation for my summer holiday and then m̶o̶c̶k̶ get SE to sent me a tee shirt :D ([source](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3517185#3517185)\)

Comment: Damn I wish I had seen this before. I was attempting to get my MSO Fanatic badge and had to plan the first two days of my recent trip to Budapest to ensure I didn't fail at the last hurdle! :)

Answer (score 2):

The principle purpose of badges is that they reward behaviour that Stack Overflow wants to encourage in its users. We want them to vote so we have badges for voting etc.

It would not benefit Stack Overflow if we discouraged folks from visiting it.

Having said that, from a purely keeping you sane point of view, taking a break from anything you've been doing for 200 days solid is surely a good idea, I just don't think it fulfils the criteria for getting a badge.

Comment: Why not have the Fanatic badge be able to be awarded multiple times then?

Comment: Once they have you hooked, you'll keep going back to your supplier without any need of additional reward ;-)

Comment: @RobertLongson I... [well, I confirm](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122976/6309).