# I'd like to introduce new tag [ko] and make it a synonym for [knockout.js]

Tags: discussion

**This question has no other purpose than to satisfy SO's requirements for creating a new tag.**

I was actually surprised to find that there is no [ko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ko) tag in the system yet, so I couldn't suggest it as a synonym to [knockout.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/knockout.js).

Since it is [required to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) in order to create a tag, this exists.

#### Edit: Just so everyone realizes why I went down this path:

> ## How do I create a new tag?
>
> Simply enter a new tag with your question and it will be created.

### Please do not close this as the problem is still not solved properly as long as the help system clearly tells you a different story.

Comment: There's no ko tag in the system because no one has evidently needed to use it.  I don't think creating tags for the sake of creating synonyms is the right thing to be doing, especially by "asking" a bad question just to create the tag in the first place.  Is there a meta post/precedent for doing so somewhere?

Comment: Well, the system requires you to ask a question in order to create a tag. This is the problem in the first place. Don't blame me for a crappy process.

Comment: That's what I mean though - perhaps it doesn't exist because when people are asking questions, they're quite happily finding and using the existing knockout.js tag?  Is there any evidence to suggest that people are mistagging their knockout questions because they can't find a suitable tag?

Comment: If that were the case, I couldn't be aware of it. I noticed it is not available when searching for  "[ko] some search terms" today. Among Knockout.js developers, KO is the common abbreviation everyone uses. The library even namespaces all its functionality `ko.`.

Comment: @rene I'm not sure this is a duplicate - the answer says _"As an alternative, you can request the creation of a tag by starting a new meta discussion. This gives other people the opportunity to discuss if the new tag is needed."_ - isn't this such a discussion?

Comment: OK, I'm fine with that @JamesThorpe

Comment: I just sticked to what the help system says is required to add a new tag: "How do I create a new tag?

Simply enter a new tag with your question and it will be created." So it would be nice if people could stop downvoting what is seriosuly meant to help improve the site. If this is not the intended way, then **make yourself clear in your help system**.

Comment: @connexo there is nowhere in the help *invent a question*... and I don't see this happen often so I guess the help center is clear enough.

Comment: Regardless of how often this happens, the help text clearly is **not clear enough** on this issue. Not a word mentioned about adding a tag to an existing question in order to create a tag, let alone that this is the recommended way to do it. You cannot expect people to search meta SO before using site functionality IMHO.

Comment: @connexo If you feel the documentation isn't good enough, meta is the place to bring it up.  Ask a new question (on meta!) with discussion and/or feature request tags with details about what you think is bad with it, and explain why you think it needs to be changed.  Even better if you suggest some alternative wording for it.

Comment: At 15 downvotes I will delete this question. It's not worth my time, my nerves - and my reputation - to experience this while trying to help improve the site.

Comment: @connexo Votes on meta have no affect on reputation - as I mentioned in a comment below, it's more of a mechanism to indicate agreement.  [Here's one of my suggestions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295733/badge-propsal-vacation) that the community didn't agree with :)

Comment: So this is why I have -14 on my reputation today?

Comment: @connexo At a guess, that will get reversed when the overnight scripts run since the question got migrated away from the main site

Comment: It has not reversed, and people still keep downvoting. I guess this was my first and also my last attempt at helping SO improve.

Answer (score 6):

I don't believe this extra tag/synonym is needed.  Indeed, when tagging your question, if you type in "ko" into the tag search box, the first (at least it used to be until a few minutes ago!) result is for knockout anway:

[image]

In addition, [a search](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com+ko+-knockout.js) for questions that mention "ko" but *not* "knockout.js" (ie ones that might be about knockout but don't use [knockout.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/knockout.js) seems to turn up a lot of questions about linux kernel modules (and none that are asking about knockout - one is asking about knockout equivalent functionality, but in angular), suggesting that this would be an ambiguous tag anyway.

Comment: That's because he added it by first posting his question to SO before it got migrated to meta.  It should disappear again.

Comment: @Hans [Yeah, I know](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)... - that's why I still said it's the "first result" :)

Comment: The discussion shouldn't be about "is it needed" but rather "is it helpful/does it make sense/does it improve SO". Just my 2 cents.

Comment: @connexo It may be worth editing your question now it's over on meta to include your rationale for wanting to create it - alternatively set out the reason for doing so in an answer.  The voting on meta is more of an "I agree/disagree" mechanism than anything.  If an alternative "let's create it" answer gets more votes, let's go ahead and create it (but not by adding an otherwise pointless question :))